# Entity Framework include items only by condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I need my context to include the `sonns` by a condition, I need the rows that not deleted (logical delete).

I understood that I cannot add a condition to the include; so I want to filter the context, but it's not working.

```
var aa = ctx.aa
         .Include(t => t.vari)
         .ToList()
         .FirstOrDefault();

ctx.vari.Where(bi => bi.ID == 10 && bi.Deleted == 1).ToList();
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ctx.vari.Where(bi => bi.ID == 10 && bi.Deleted == 1).ToList();` You've missed the bi for ID. Otherwise can you mention the error you are having?

Comment: you are right! (I think that the idea of the question was  clear  despite of the mistake....)

Comment: Good to hear. Then you can vote for my comment. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As codelahiru && hbulens pointed out, you missed the bi for ID.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

The Query IncludeOptimized feature allows to filter with include and optimize the query performance at the same time (Support EF5, EF6)

```
var aa = ctx.aa
            .IncludeOptimized(t => t.vari.Where(bi => bi.ID == 10 && bi.Deleted == 1))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Documentation: [EF+ Query IncludeOptimized](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-optimized)

Comment: Looks beuatiful !! but I can't have EF Plus :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use a third party library? The code is free & open source so if you want you can either grab the source from GitHub or contact me and I will send you a zip file with only the EF+ Query IncludeOptimized source code.

Comment: thanks' you are so kind. i will ask my boss

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be the most performant query. It would be better to drop the ToList()

```
 var aa = ctx.aa.Include(t => t.vari).ToList().FirstOrDefault(); 

 // You missed the variable before ID
 ctx.vari.Where(bi => bi.ID == 10 && bi.Deleted == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: exactly what i did...

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: @abarisone Normally I'd agree with you but the scope of the issue is so small there is little need for explanation (it was merely a typo imo).

Comment: oh! I did it, I needed to filter the contex without the .include sentence. I think that the sosns were included, i just needed to 'touch' them.... Thanks!